# calculate yearly return of prices over many years

Tags: sql, oracle

I have rows containing prices every day for an, example stock price or the price of Snickers doesn't really matter

date = dd.mm.yyyy

```
row | date       | price
1   | 1.1.2015   | 23.3
2   | 4.5.2015   | 25.8
3   | 6.9.2015   | 27.3
4   | 31.12.2015 | 28.1
...
5   | 1.1.2016   | 28.1
6   | 7.10.2016  | 29.3
7   | 2.11.2016  | 30.3
8   | 31.12.2016 | 33.3
...
9   | 1.1.2017   | 33.3
10  | 3.1.2017   | 39.7
11  | 15.9.2017 | 41.2
```

The dates between 1.1 and 31.12 don't really matter here in this example. I am just looking at the price of first day of the year and then the last day of the year.

Example result would be for this data:

```
row | year | return
1   | 2015 | 20%
2   | 2016 | 23%
3   | 2017 | 20%
```

How can I group the rows into years, and also calculate the difference between the rows that have the dates: first day of that current year 1.1, and the last day of the year 31.12?

Comment: Did you really store the dates as strings?

Comment: @juergend: Well this is an example but if you want to use date functions on dates it would probably be a wise thing to have date column as date types in the database. But that is not the what we are discussing here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want the value on the first of the year and the last of the year for the calculation:

```
select rownum as "row", to_char(date, 'YYYY') as yyyy,
       max(price) keep (dense_rank first order by date asc) as first_price,
       max(price) keep (dense_rank first order by date desc) as last_price,
       ( (max(price) keep (dense_rank first order by date desc) /
          max(price) keep (dense_rank first order by date asc)
         ) - 1
       ) as "return"
from t
group by to_char(date, 'YYYY') 
order by to_char(date, 'YYYY') ;
```

Note:  This assumes that you want the first and last days in the data, as opposed to Jan 1st and Dec 31st.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the year and then you can find the highest price on the first day of the year (`MAX( price ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY year )`) and the lowest price on the last day of the year (`MIN( price ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST  ORDER BY year )`) and calculate the percentage increase between those two values:

```
SELECT rownum AS "row",
       EXTRACT( YEAR FROM "date" ) AS year,
       ( MIN( price ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST  ORDER BY year )
         / MAX( price ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY year )
         * 100
       ) - 100
         AS "return"
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY EXTRACT( YEAR FROM "date" )
```